# solve $\cos 2x - 5\sin x + 2 = 0$ using addition formulae

Tags: trigonometry

> solve $\cos 2x - 5\sin x + 2 = 0, 0^{\circ} \le x \le 360^{\circ}$

I am going to use this formula for $\cos 2x$

$\cos 2x = 1 - 2\sin^2 x$

=> $1 - 2\sin^2x - 5\sin x + 2 = 0$

=> $2\sin^2x - 5\sin x + 3 = 0$

$\sin x(2x - 3)(x -1) =0$

From here I get:

$x = \arcsin -\frac{3}{2}$

and

$x = \arcsin -1$

Could I please have answers using addition formulae and not the unit circle as I have not covered that yet.

Comment: $\cos 2x=1-\color{red}{2}\sin^2 x$.

Comment: @mathlove thank you, I have updated the question

Comment: $(2\sin x -3)(\sin x -1)=0$

Comment: But $2\sin x -3 \not = 0$. Then $\sin x=1$

Comment: $2\sin^2x-5\sin x+3=0$ is wrong. $2\sin ^2x\color{red}{+}5\sin x\color{red}{-}3=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your factorization is wrong. From the line $2sin^2x-5sinx+3=0$ you have
$$u= sinx$$
$$2sin^2x-5sinx+3=0 \rightarrow 2u^2-5x+3=0$$
$$(2u-3)(u-1)=0$$
$$2u-3=0 \rightarrow u= \frac{3}{2}$$
$$sinx= \frac{3}{2} \rightarrow x \in C$$
$$u-1=0 \rightarrow sinx=1$$
$$x= 90^o$$

Comment: what does $sinx= \frac{3}{2} \rightarrow x \in C$ mean?

Comment: also why does $u = \sin x$

Comment: C is the complex numbers. An imaginary argument could get sin(x) >1. u= sin(x) is just a substitution to make factorization more obvious. I was not sure in the OP if sinx(2x-3)(x-1) was meant to be sin(x)*(2x-3)*(x-1) or if the factorization was (2x-3)(x-1) where x is really sin(x). Using x to replace sin(x) was confusing.

Comment: $2\sin ^2x-5\sin x+3=0$ is wrong.

Comment: are you saying that $sinx = \frac{3}2$ is not a valid answer and x = 90 is the only valid answer.  Would it be possible to update your answer?  I am very interested to know.

Comment: Mathlove is right. It should be $2sin^2x+5sinx-3=0$. The factorization is then (2u-1)(u+3)=0. Still ignore |sinx|>1.

Comment: @mathlove is right, I've updated the question.  This should make $x = -\frac{3}{2}$ or $x = -1$ and I should ignore the $x = -\frac{3}2$?

Comment: Yup, it is more than justifiable to ignore sin x >1 (<-1). The same is true for cos x.